# Multi-Layered Searching in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with a list of states, elections in each state, politicians in any given senate/governor race, and the party affiliations of each of those politicians. I would like to create a bar denoting whether each race has a Libertarian competing in it. In my head, it looks something like this:

1. Create range that includes all rows.
2. Check current politician's state. Narrow range to include only rows from that state.
3. Check current politician's race. Narrow range to include only rows from that race.
4. Use COUNTIF to count the number of times "Libertarian Party" appears in the range.
5. If number > 0, there is a Libertarian in a race. Return TRUE. Else return FALSE.

See here for example spreadsheet. [SPREADSHEET.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kadj4.png)

What is the actual code for this? What commands should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a COUNTIFS formula like:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,D:D,"Libertarian Party")>0,"TRUE","FALSE")
```